# IE7 Animation with PNG transparency

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I've made a jQuery animation, which fades through some logoes that all uses PNG transparency. In IE the transparency disappears. I've tried unitpngfix.js but it doesn't work.

[The site is here.](http://a2.boxx.dk/beta/)

Note: Try using Firefox to see the wanted effect.

Can any of you, see what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

IE<8 and Chrome 1 doesn't play nice with png32 and css opacity. I didn't find a fix :(